# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Calculation referencing Previous Row

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, excel-formula

I am looking to design a query, where a calculation compares a value in a cell with a value in the previous cell in the same column, and another calculation uses the previous calculations result to reference a previous cell for a calculation as well. The data will be in the following order from the sample image below - Material, Plant and YearWeek

[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3bAC.png)

From the image below, the blue column headers represent the raw data, and the yellow column headers represent the calculation rows.

The formulae for the calculation rows are as follows:

- First? = IF(AND(B2=B1,C2=C1),"No","First")
- Actual Available = IF(F2="First",D2-E2,G1-E2)

From my investigation, the LEAD and LAG functions can help accomplish this, but since I am restricted to SQL Server 2008 R2, I am unable to use them. Please find the query to create the table.

```
    CREATE TABLE ZDAYS ([YearWeek] VARCHAR(7), 
    [Material] VARCHAR(3), [Plant] VARCHAR(3),
    [Inventory] INT, [Demand] INT)

    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'ABC', '101', 20, 5)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'ABC', '101', 20, 3)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'ABC', '101', 20, 2)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'ABC', '201', 30, 10)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'ABC', '201', 30, 8)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'ABC', '201', 30, 4)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'XYZ', '101', 10, 3)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'XYZ', '101', 10, 2)
    INSERT INTO ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'XYZ', '201', 20, 4)
```

Final Data Output

```
 YearWeek   Material    Plant   Inventory   Demand  First?  Actual Available
 2015-42    ABC          101        20        5     First         15             
 2015-43    ABC          101        20        3     No            12             
 2015-44    ABC          101        20        2     No            10
 2015-42    ABC          201        30        10    First         20
 2015-43    ABC          201        30        8     No            12
 2015-44    ABC          201        30        4     No            8
 2015-42    XYZ          101        10        3     First         7
 2015-43    XYZ          101        10        2     No            5
 2015-44    XYZ          201        20        4     First         16
```

Comment: You should include the results that you want in your question.  A question should not rely on an external web site.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff , since I am new here, can you let me know the format you want to see the final results in? I have attached a sample image of what I am expecting, but I don't know how to post the data here in a row and column format.

Comment: You can put four spaces at the beginning of a line to get a tabular or code format.  Alternatively, you can highlight several rows and click on `{}`.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, I have added the Final output I want to see. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from answer 'No Joins and No Analytic Functions' at:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/

```
declare  @ZDAYS TABLE ([YearWeek] VARCHAR(7), 
    [Material] VARCHAR(3), [Plant] VARCHAR(3),
    [Inventory] INT, [Demand] INT)

    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'ABC', '101', 20, 5)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'ABC', '101', 20, 3)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'ABC', '101', 20, 2)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'ABC', '201', 30, 10)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'ABC', '201', 30, 8)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'ABC', '201', 30, 4)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'XYZ', '101', 10, 3)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'XYZ', '101', 10, 2)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'XYZ', '201', 20, 4);

WITH T1 (RowNum, UniqueID, YearWeek, Material, Plant, Inventory, Demand)
AS
    (SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY z.Material,z.Plant,z.YearWeek ) N
        ,1.0 + floor(10000 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) as UniqueID 
        ,z.YearWeek
        ,z.Material
        ,z.Plant
        ,z.Inventory
        ,z.Demand
        FROM @ZDAYS z
    )
select T1.*,
CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=0 THEN UniqueID END) OVER (Partition BY (RowNum+1)/2) ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN UniqueID END) OVER (Partition BY RowNum/2) END LeadValUniqueID,
CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=0 THEN UniqueID END) OVER (Partition BY RowNum/2) ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN UniqueID END) OVER (Partition BY (RowNum+1)/2) END LagValUniqueID
FROM T1
ORDER BY T1.Material, T1.Plant, T1.YearWeek
GO
```

or, the same logic with the Lead() and Lag() rows concatenated for identification instead of generating a unique id.

```
declare  @ZDAYS TABLE ([YearWeek] VARCHAR(7), 
    [Material] VARCHAR(3), [Plant] VARCHAR(3),
    [Inventory] INT, [Demand] INT)

    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'ABC', '101', 20, 5)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'ABC', '101', 20, 3)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'ABC', '101', 20, 2)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'ABC', '201', 30, 10)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'ABC', '201', 30, 8)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'ABC', '201', 30, 4)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-42', 'XYZ', '101', 10, 3)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-43', 'XYZ', '101', 10, 2)
    INSERT INTO @ZDAYS VALUES ('2015-44', 'XYZ', '201', 20, 4);

-- LAG and LEAD result rows concatenated
WITH T1 (RowNum,  YearWeek, Material, Plant, Inventory, Demand)
AS
    (SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY z.Material,z.Plant,z.YearWeek ) N
        ,z.YearWeek
        ,z.Material
        ,z.Plant
        ,z.Inventory
        ,z.Demand
        FROM @ZDAYS z
    )
select T1.*,
CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=0 THEN YearWeek + ' ' + Material + ' ' + Plant + ' ' + cast(Inventory as varchar(5)) + ' ' + cast(Demand as varchar(5)) END) OVER (Partition BY (RowNum+1)/2) ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN YearWeek + ' ' + Material + ' ' + Plant + ' ' + cast(Inventory as varchar(5)) + ' ' + cast(Demand as varchar(5)) END) OVER (Partition BY RowNum/2) END LeadRowValues,
CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=0 THEN YearWeek + ' ' + Material + ' ' + Plant + ' ' + cast(Inventory as varchar(5)) + ' ' + cast(Demand as varchar(5)) END) OVER (Partition BY RowNum/2) ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum%2=1 THEN YearWeek + ' ' + Material + ' ' + Plant + ' ' + cast(Inventory as varchar(5)) + ' ' + cast(Demand as varchar(5)) END) OVER (Partition BY (RowNum+1)/2) END LagRowValues
FROM T1
ORDER BY T1.Material, T1.Plant, T1.YearWeek
GO
```

Comment: @Shantanu please mark as solved if this solution worked for you.

Comment: Hi Shep, I tried your solution and it does emulate the Lag and Lead function, but that is not the final solution I am looking for. Check my latest edit to see the output I am expecting, i.e., 'Actual Available' column.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of SQL Server you can use `apply`:

```
select z.yearweek, z.material, z.plant, z.inventory, z.demand,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as isFirst,
       (inventory - cume.demand) as ActualAvailable
from (select z.*,
             row_number() over (partition by material, plant order by yearweek) as seqnum
      from zdays z
     ) z outer apply
     (select sum(z2.demand) as demand
      from zdays z2
      where z2.material = z.material and z2.plant = z.plant and
            z2.yearweek <= z.yearweek
     ) cume
```